# How to convert any format(.txt, .Doc) file into epub file in android application

Tags: android, epub, file-format, file-conversion, ebook-reader

I am developing an application in which I have to read or write any eBook.

In android so many libraries available for reading any eBook, but for writing i didn't find any thing.

For reading any eBook file must be in .epub format.

I have an editor in which i am entering some text and after saving that file in any format how can i convert that file into .epub file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, anybody please tell me the link of such a library.

Comment: Try http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android Java is developer language for create APP, use [Epublib](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib/android) (lib in java)

Read "doc file" with [poi](http://poi.apache.org/document/)

Create epub file:

```
package nl.siegmann.epublib.examples;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Author;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Metadata;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Resource;
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.TOCReference;

import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubWriter;

public class Translator {
  private static InputStream getResource( String path ) {
    return Translator.class.getResourceAsStream( path );
  }

  private static Resource getResource( String path, String href ) {
    return new Resource( getResource( path ), href );
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      // Create new Book
      Book book = new Book();
      Metadata metadata = book.getMetadata();

      // Set the title
      metadata.addTitle("Epublib test book 1");

      // Add an Author
      metadata.addAuthor(new Author("Joe", "Tester"));

      // Set cover image
      book.setCoverImage(
        getResource("/book1/test_cover.png", "cover.png") );

      // Add Chapter 1
      book.addSection("Introduction",
        getResource("/book1/chapter1.html", "chapter1.html") );

      // Add css file
      book.getResources().add(
        getResource("/book1/book1.css", "book1.css") );

      // Add Chapter 2
      TOCReference chapter2 = book.addSection( "Second Chapter",
        getResource("/book1/chapter2.html", "chapter2.html") );

      // Add image used by Chapter 2
      book.getResources().add(
        getResource("/book1/flowers_320x240.jpg", "flowers.jpg"));

      // Add Chapter2, Section 1
      book.addSection(chapter2, "Chapter 2, section 1",
        getResource("/book1/chapter2_1.html", "chapter2_1.html"));

      // Add Chapter 3
      book.addSection("Conclusion",
        getResource("/book1/chapter3.html", "chapter3.html"));

      // Create EpubWriter
      EpubWriter epubWriter = new EpubWriter();

      // Write the Book as Epub
      epubWriter.write(book, new FileOutputStream("test1_book1.epub"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```